# DataGridView ComboBoxColumn. Как показать только те значения, которые соответствуют условию?

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

```
prTasksCaptionsNpgsqlDataAdapter = new NpgsqlDataAdapter("SELECT tasksCaptions.id, tasksCaptions.organizationsID, organizations.name AS organizationsName, tasksCaptions.objectsID, objects.name AS objectsName FROM \"prMk\".tasksCaptions INNER JOIN \"prMk\".organizations ON tasksCaptions.organizationsID = organizations.id INNER JOIN \"prMk\".objects ON tasksCaptions.objectsID = objects.id ORDER BY tasksCaptions.id; SELECT id, name FROM \"prMk\".organizations ORDER BY name; SELECT id, organizationsID, name FROM \"prMk\".objects ORDER BY name", con);
prTasksCaptionsDataSet = new DataSet();
con.Open();
prTasksCaptionsNpgsqlDataAdapter.Fill(prTasksCaptionsDataSet);
con.Close();
prTasksCaptionsDataTable = new DataTable();
prTasksCaptionsDataTable = prTasksCaptionsDataSet.Tables[0];
dgvPrTasksCaptions.DataSource = prTasksCaptionsDataTable;

DataGridViewComboBoxColumn objectsIDDataGridViewComboBoxColumn = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
DataTable sprObjectsDataTable = new DataTable();
prTasksCaptionsDataTable = prTasksCaptionsDataSet.Tables[2];
objectsIDDataGridViewComboBoxColumn.DataSource = sprObjectsDataTable;
objectsIDDataGridViewComboBoxColumn.ValueMember = "id";
objectsIDDataGridViewComboBoxColumn.DisplayMember = "name";
objectsIDDataGridViewComboBoxColumn.DataPropertyName = "objectsID";
dgvPrTasksCaptions.Columns.Add(objectsIDDataGridViewComboBoxColumn);
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как показывать в выпадающем списке каждой строки только те значения, у которых совпадает ключ "organizationsID"? Сейчас в списке я вижу всю таблицу "objects", а не в зависимости от значения "organizationsID" каждой строки из таблицы "tasksCaptions"

```
sprObjectsDataTable.DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("organizationsID = {0}", dgvPrTasksCaptions.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString());
```

С этим программа вылетает с исключением "System.ArgumentException" когда я перехожу на строку с другим значением ключа... Пробовал сбрасывать фильтр в разных событиях. Ругается в "Display", "Formatting"...

Comment: Добавьте к вопросу теги winforms и sql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void dgvPrTasksCaptions_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{

    if (((DataGridView)sender).CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 8)
    {
        testNpgsqlDataAdapter = new NpgsqlDataAdapter("SELECT id, name FROM \"prMk\".objects WHERE organizationsID = " + dgvPrTasksCaptions.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString() + " ORDER BY name", con);
        testDataSet = new DataSet();
        con.Open();
        testNpgsqlDataAdapter.Fill(testDataSet);
        con.Close();
        testDataTable = new DataTable();
        testDataTable = testDataSet.Tables[0];
        ((DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl)e.Control).DataSource = testDataTable; 
        ((DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl)e.Control).DisplayMember = "name";
        ((DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl)e.Control).ValueMember = "id";
    }
}
```